# Running asyncio coroutine out of the event flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm having issues where my call to `api.say()` fails. I understand its a coroutine and needs to be yielded from but is that valid if my `print_all` is a standard function.

What is the correct way to structure this example?

Please assume that the Client isn't changeable, only the code in my example.

```
from .client import Client
import asyncio

api = Client()
login = ('', '')

def print_all(b=None, m=None):
    print("Buffer!", b)
    print("Message", m)

    if b and m:
        if b.name == 'bat':
            print("-sending to", b)
            api.say(b, "Hey yo."):    # <----


def main():
    api.login(*login)
    api.register_message_callback(print_all)
    api.register_state_callback(print_all)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(api.run())
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Client API might handle callbacks that are coroutines too i.e., you can convert `print_all()` into a coroutine (prepend `async` before `def`, add `await` before `api.say()`).

Otherwise, you could call `asyncio.ensure_future(api.say(..))` to schedule the coroutine. It assumes that `loop.run_until_complete(api.run())` won't return before `api.say()` is done i.e., there is `loop.run_forever()` equivalent in your program or you wait for all tasks -- either collected explicitly or implicitly (`asyncio.Task.all_tasks()`).

Comment: Thanks `asyncio.ensure_future(api.say(..)) ` fixed the issue. My client didn't handle the callbacks as coroutines so `.ensure_future(...)` sorted it out.